# How can i align my tableLayouts to the center?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

**UPDATE 2**

The horizontalscrollview is bugged, it cuts part of the table.

This is the first table, the scrollview doesnt move and cuts the first cell.

[image]

The second table it has Scroll but the limits are wrong... 
Scrolled max to the right.

[image]

Scrolled max to the left leaves a blank space.

[image]

**Update 3**

Copied the exactly layout to another similar fragment and doesn't align to the center, but the horizontalScroll works fine. This randomness is killing me.

**The updated layout:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="acr.acr_app.MyFragment3">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/textCompresores"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:stretchColumns="60dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center">
        </Spinner>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:fillViewport="true">
                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:stretchColumns="*"
                    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
                </TableLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:fillViewport="true">
                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:stretchColumns="*"
                    android:id="@+id/tableLayout2">
                </TableLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did u try with _android:layout_centerInParent="true"_?

Comment: Just tried it with the same result, the horizontalScrollview doesn't works properly neither. I'm using the same layout for 4 tables and the only it doesn't work it's the first one.

Comment: so you want your `TableLayout` to put in center of the screen right? may I know how exactly do you want? since you have two `TableLayout` inside a `HorizontalScrollView` which is inside a `RelativeLayout`...can you show a preview of layout for better understanding...

Comment: Probably some of the layouts arent needed... I just need to move the table from top-left to the center. The relative layout is for overlapping the tables.

Comment: Try adding this line to the parent of your tableLayout 

"android:layout_gravity = "center""

Comment: That worked for me but the horizontalScroll cuts the left of the table. I will update the image .

Comment: I still didn't get why you have used two `tableLayout`. You have only one table right??

Comment: I'm changing the table with the selection from the spinner.

Comment: oh ok so one of them has visibility `GONE` right?

Comment: Please check my answer and accept if it meets your requirements!

Comment: i will accept it later, but i still got the same problem the same problem with that layout and another fragment, and new ones with the horizontalScroll. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="acr.acr_app.MyFragment3">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/scrollView3" >

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top|center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:stretchColumns="60dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center">
</Spinner>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true">
             <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
            </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout2">
        </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the above code I have removed the redundant `LinearLayout` which was parent of `TableLayout` since we should avoid using too many nested layouts when not really necessary and I have stretched the `scrollView` so that child can be placed in centre if child has smaller width than screen. Please try this code and if any issue please let me know in the comment section.